# REST API - Not Logging Out - Open Sessions

Tags: acumatica

I know that I need to make sure that I'm logging out when working with the REST API. But if my program has crashed a few times before the logout could happen, I know there are some hanging sessions out there. Is there a way to kill those open sessions? Or do I just need to restart IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim, your program should be written in a way to not completely crash when an exception is thrown. Ideally, it must handle all REST API exceptions and store them in a log file for further analysis.

If you don't log out, IIS will automatically close an open session once the configured session timeout expires (see [Acumatica product help](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=54775fb6-60d7-4995-99c0-8349f9b5d356) for more details). There is no way to "kill" an open session. If you restart IIS or recycle an app pool, you will close all open connections, both with API and web browsers.

Comment: One amend: if a persistent session storage is enabled (e.g., in cluster deployment), restarting IIS/app pool won't help, the sessions will be there until expiration.